# Do chat messages send notifications to the original poster (or question asker) without a direct notification (aka @username)?

Tags: support, chat, notifications

Do chat messages send notifications to the original poster (or question asker) without a direct notification (aka @username)? For example, if the comments are moved to a chatroom and I send a chat message directed at someone. That someone sends a message without @myusername. Will I still get a notification about this if I am the original poster to the question this chatroom is about. Would it matter whether or not I was the one who moved the comments to a chat room?

If chat notifications aren't done by adding @username, then please clarify the method for creating a directed notification to a user.

Comment: You will not receive notifications magically. You will only be pinged once you joined the room. Joining is not automatic, each user has to do this on  their own.

Comment: @rene So one will not get any emails about a chat message? I have multiple chat rooms I would like to be "in the loop" on. But I forget which of my posts ended up in a chat room. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That someone sends a message without @myusername. Will I still get a notification about this if I am the original poster to the question this chatroom is about

**No**. You won't get notified if the user has not pinged (aka mentioned) you. That works in comments, but once it is moved to chat, you won't get notified for each message in that room.

You will be pingable only if you joined the chat room.

Once you left, if you posted any message, you will still be pingable using the first 3 letters for the next 2 days and full name for next 7 days. If they pinged using that format, you will get notified. If you left the room without posting anything, you will not be pingable at all.

The comments are moved to chat but the room have it's own characteristics and existence. So, if you want to get notified, they have to ping you.

Comment: (1) If the chatroom was from a moved comment section and I posted a comment on that comment section, would I need to post a message in order to be pingable, or would I need to post on the chatroom? (2) Would I need to leave as I was the latest message? (3) Do pings (that meet all the criteria mentioned) send out email notifications?

Comment: pings won't send you email. you don't need to post. but if you entered the room, they will be able to ping you

Answer (score 3):

When someone starts a chat because a comment exchange has become convoluted, most likely one of these comments with a link to the chat will be posted under your post, triggering a notification to you (like all comments on your post)

> Let us continue this conversation in chat

or

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat

(This will only notify a person or people in the conversation if they would normally have been notified of the message, i.e. if they are the only person apart from the post owner who has commented so far.)

Otherwise, one of you will have created the chat room and posted a link to it.

There are no other notifications unless you join the room *and* someone mentions you with @user (pings you). If someone pings you, you will be notified as long as you have been in the room in the last few days.

In other words, there's no special mechanism beyond the automatic suggestion to move to chat. You don't get any notifications that you wouldn't normally get.