# How can I link other questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, linked-questions

I asked the question
[Linking to other Music SE questions](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/linking-to-other-music-se-questions) and it was suggested to ask it here.

The question is: Sometimes I don't have an answer to write, but I know other questions worth linking. How can I do it?

Links put in the comments are not robust, as moderators tend move extended comment discussions to chat and then links from comments disappear as well. I fell like linking is an important part of building a question database. What is a proper way to link questions?

Answer (score 3):

If the other question contains answers to the question then "link" it as a duplicate.

If it's not quite a "duplicate" then a comment on the question saying that it's related is OK.

Never write an "answer" that consists of only links to other's questions and/or answers. Your answer must stand on its own as a complete answer.

Helpful comments usually are not deleted.

Comment: *"Helpful comments usually are not deleted."* True, but they can get moved to chat, and when that happens, any questions linked in them disappear from the Linked section, as the OP mentioned. And unless you revisit that page, you have no way of knowing that your helpful links have vanished.

Comment: @PM2Ring, A Feature Req here on meta will address any shortcomings that you find with the present system. Link only answers or plagiarism are not the solution to address the problem you mentioned. Such issues are addressed in these Q&As: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268708/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323515/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341754/282094, etc. --- This is the duplicate to your new question written as a comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323504/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332385/282094 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302185/282094

Comment: FWIW, I'd already upvoted *Notify me for ping from a comment moved to chat*. I certainly was *not* suggesting that anyone should post link-only answers, or engage in plagiarism (I often flag such answers when I see them), and I'm a little puzzled that you thought my previous comment was suggesting those things.

Comment: When you write "Helpful comments usually are not deleted", do you mean that in my case the moderator considered my link unhelpful, rather than they moved large number of comments to chat without considering usefulness each of them individually?

Comment: @user1079505 Yes. There's been a lot of replies recently, and [as Yaakov explained](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8741754#8741754) time spent in one place detracts from the time available to assist people who really need the help; that's unfortunate but the one word answer will have to suffice.